# Multiply td values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table that looks like this...

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Pair</th>
     <th>Game</th>
     <th>Chance</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2014-2-12</td>
     <td>Milan-Udinese</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1.6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2014-2-13</td>
     <td>Juventus-Inter</td>
     <td>x</td>
     <td>2.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2014-2-13</td>
     <td>Arsenal-Liverpul</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>2.5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<p>Total number is:MULTIPLICATION OF ALL CHANCE COLUMN TD</p>
```

all my rows are added dynamically,how do i multiply all chance column td values(numbers)?Do i have to put certain class on chance tds and then get all tds with that class,and loop through and multiply every value then?I'm kinda a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the rows are added dynamically (from db maybe?) why not have that process just return a total row.

Comment: it's not from db,i am transferring data from one table to another on button click...

Comment: If you can't return the results from the query, it would be much easier to just give the `<td>` a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do something like this:

```
var tots = 1;

$('tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
  tots *= $(this).text();
});
```

the nth-child(4) is selecting the fourth td in each row, if you want another, just change that number.

or you can give the cells you want to multiple classes, like you said.

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6m8J9/)

Comment: He wants to add the "chance" column, so he would need `nth-child(4)`, but otherwise this is a good answer!

Comment: You should parse those values

Comment: because i add rows dynamically(on button click) this code is not working...i think i have to listen to table row change and then execute this code,any clues?

Comment: @Shile you can execute this code after the code that dynamically adds the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, the `:last-child` selector could be helpful.

```
<p>Total number is: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
res = 1;
$("tr td:last-child").each(function() {
    res *= parseFloat($(this).html());
});


$("#result").html(res);
```

Have a look to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLcn6/2/).

Comment: If you add another column in the future, there's a danger here in using `:last-child`. For this reason I like using `nth-child(4)` better. However, using `parseFloat` is a very good idea.

Comment: yea i realized after I asked that there were decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to do this. `querySelectorAll` supports `nth-child` selector as well.

```
var derp = document.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-child(4)");
var total = 1;
var results = [].reduce.call(derp, function (prev, next) {
    return prev * ( + next.textContent );
});
```

Grab the element, and use native `Array` prototype methods (`[]`) to iterate the `NodeList` and return the parsed value of the element, then return the multiplied total.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bC7Tt/8/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var chanceTotals = 1;
    $("tr td:nth-child(4)").each(function () {
        chanceTotals *= parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $("#totals").html("Total number is: " + chanceTotals);
});
```

Using jQuery, this executes an anonymous function when the document is ready that will do the calculation for you.

You will need to add the id `totals` to your `p` element in order for this to work.

Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZmrK/)

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need jquery at all to do this. Interacting with the DOM directly may make you write more (browser support), but it can be more efficient than using jQuery (Unnecessary overhead).

As you can see, I restructured your `<table>`. I could have just grabbed the `<tbody>` and looped over its children and skipped the whole `if <TD> ?` check.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/Kw2My/#base)</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').get(0);
    var multiplier = 1;
    var col = 3;

    for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        var cell = table.rows[row].cells[col];

        if (cell.nodeName == 'TD') {
            var text = cell.innerText || cell.textContent;
            multiplier *= parseFloat(text);
        }
    }

    $('#multiplier').text(multiplier);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Pair</th>
            <th>Game</th>
            <th>Chance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2014-2-12</td>
            <td>Milan-Udinese</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2014-2-13</td>
            <td>Juventus-Inter</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>2.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2014-2-13</td>
            <td>Arsenal-Liverpul</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2.5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Total number is:
    <span id="multiplier">MULTIPLICATION OF ALL CHANCE COLUMN TD</span>
</p>
```